# adding css class from code behind on page load asp.net C# using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have below code. what I am trying to do is apply the CSS class from code behind c# with javascript only without using runat server attribute.

In the code behind, I am using below script, but it is not adding the class active. What I am doing wrong here?

C# Code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "script", 
    "<script type=text/javascript> $('#pendingtask').addClass('tab-pane fade in active');</script>", 
    false);
```

View/page:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="pendingtask">
   <div class="row col-sm-12">
      <div>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPending"  runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:ListView ID="lvPendingTask" runat="server" DataKeyNames="EXV_KEY" OnItemCommand="lvPendingTask_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="lvPendingTask_ItemDataBound">
                  <LayoutTemplate>
                     <table id="datatable_fixed_column" class="table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-bordered table-condensed" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                           <tr>
                              <th style="width: 30px">ID</th>
                              <th>Task</th>
                              <th>Stage</th>
                              <th>Status</th>

                              <th style="width: 120px">Options</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </LayoutTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                           <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EXV_KEY") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td><%#Eval("TASK_DESC")%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("STAGE_DESC")%></td>
                        <td><%#Eval("ts_desc_eng")%></td>

                        <td>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPrint" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" Visible="False"  CommandName="PrintLetter" runat="server"  OnClientClick="showOverlay();"> Print</asp:LinkButton>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCompleteTask" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" Visible="False" CommandName="CompleteTask" runat="server"  OnClientClick="showOverlay();"> Mark Complete</asp:LinkButton>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnEdit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" Visible="False" CommandName="EditTask" runat="server"  OnClientClick="showOverlay();"> Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnDelete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" Visible="False" CommandName="Delete" runat="server"> Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EmptyDataTemplate>
                     <p> 
                     <h5><span class="label label-danger">No Record Found!  </span></h5>
                     </p>
                  </EmptyDataTemplate>
               </asp:ListView>
               <!-- end widget content -->
            </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
         <hr/>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be one of 2 problems (or both combined).

1. The first is that since you're using `jquery` to get the element
   reference, `jquery` will need to already be loaded on the page i.e.
   you *probably* couldn't run this script on page load because chances
   are `jquery` will not have loaded in the DOM by that point. You could change to pure `javascript` to test if this is the issue. The javascript below should do the same as the jquery.

   ```
   // create a string for the javascript we want to run on the page:
   string javascriptCode = @"var element = document.getElementById(""pendingTask""); element.classList.add(""tab-pane"", ""fade-in"", ""active"");";
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", javascriptCode, true);
   ```
2. The problem could be the use of
   `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` rather than
   `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. 
   `Scriptmanager.RegisterStartupScript` should be used in an
   `UpdatePanel` for asynchronous postback. Here you just want to run a
   script and insert it from the code behind,
   `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` will do that for you.

   Check the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2). The method signature for
   `ClientScript` is:

   ```
   public void RegisterStartupScript (Type type, string key, string
   script, bool addScriptTags);
   ```

   Update the code behind to this:

   ```
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", 
       "<script type=text/javascript> $('#pendingtask').addClass('tab-pane fade in active');</script>", 
       false);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: You have set the `addScriptTag` to false and you did not add the word **script** in your code. To remove the problem you can do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "script", " $('#pendingtask').addClass('tab-pane fade in active');", true);
```

Or add the word `script` at start and end of your javascript code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "script", " <script>$('#pendingtask').addClass('tab-pane fade in active');</script>", false);
```

To better understanding you can read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_ClientScriptManager_RegisterStartupScript_System_Type_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_

Comment: FYI OP did use script tags but because code was not formatted correctly the tags were stripped off. I edited question to format properly (and script tags are visible for me) but the edit is still awaiting approval.

Comment: I saw your suggested edit and I do not think this is a true edition. The questioner did not used the `script` word and it is a **way** to write this. I think you are better to leave the code in it's original.

Comment: Look at the markdown in the edit screen (not the rendered output), you can see I didn't change it :)

Comment: Ok thanks. Finally I have found the mark down and it seems that you are right.

Comment: Now what do you think? Considering the mark down my answer will be wrong?? Is it??

Comment: I don't know, it's possible it will work if the OP removes `script` tag and sets `true` like in your post. I think it is probably a different issue though